# passing meta data in body part

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

I use php for coding. Is there a way to pass meta in the body part. so that it is recognized by search engines. I know meta tags needs to be passed in head. but since i am generating pages dynamically . Only body part get changed in every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<meta>` tags must go in the `<head>` - [per the HTML specification](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_meta.asp).

Refactor your templates so you will be able to add `<meta>` tags dynamically in the head. It shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The html specs specify that `meta` tags belong in the `head` section of an HTML document.

You can generate the meta tags dynamically as well, just add them in the `head` section that you are outputting.

A php template will have head sections as well as body sections - just change them to output dynamic meta tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with [specification](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_meta.asp), it shouldn't be that difficult to even generate the meta tags dynamically like you are doing for the body part.

You can also use the [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to manipulate the html at any part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use output buffering and renew meta-data using placeholders after generating page.
Like this:

```
<?php

function callback($buffer) {

  return (ereg_replace("meta", "<META blah-bla-bla />....", $buffer));

}

ob_start("callback");

?>

<html>
<head>meta</head>
<body>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.
</body>
</html>

<?php

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a templating library such as Twig. Create blocks and extend pages and override block with more specific content.