# Do you put Schema Microdata meta tags in the html body?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I have searched for a long time across the internet and stackoverflow for an answer to this question, and I have found links that say that you should not put meta tags in the body:

- [Using HTML5+Microdata's <meta> tag in the <body>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293366/using-microdatas-meta-tag-in-html5)
- [passing meta data in body part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126926/passing-meta-data-in-body-part)
- [Meta Tags In Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820239/meta-tags-in-body)

while the schema.org website clearly shows the meta tags being nested directly in the body http://schema.org/AggregateRating

Just look at the example that is posted there

```html
 Customer reviews:

  <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <span itemprop="name">Not a happy camper</span> -
    by <span itemprop="author">Ellie</span>,
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-04-01">April 1, 2011
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1">
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">1</span>/
      <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>stars
    </div>
    <span itemprop="description">The lamp burned out and now I have to replace
    it. </span>
  </div>


 <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <span itemprop="name">Value purchase</span> -
    by <span itemprop="author">Lucas</span>,
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-03-25">March 25, 2011
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>/
      <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>stars
    </div>
    <span itemprop="description">Great microwave for the price. It is small and
    fits in my apartment.</span>
  </div>
```

If you were to keep the meta tags in the `<head>`, then how would you relate these two dates to their reviews?
`<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-04-01">`
`<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-03-25">`

This is causing confusion and I would like to know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If a `meta` element

- has an `itemprop` attribute and a `content` attribute, and
- has no `name` attribute, no `http-equiv` attribute, and no `charset` attribute,

then it’s valid to have this `meta` in the `body`. (If the value is a URL, you [must use `link` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669).)

Why? Because [the Microdata specification changes HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#content-models).

(Note that [RDFa also changes HTML5 by allowing `meta` in the `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633) in some cases.)

---

> If you were to keep the `meta` tags in the `<head>`, then how would you relate these two dates to their reviews?

You could [use the `itemref` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161277/1591669):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Using itemref for meta in the head</title>
  <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-03-25" id="date">
</head>
<body>

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemref="date">
    <span itemprop="name">…</span>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

`itemref` takes a space-separated list of `id` values, so you can even reference two or more elements. Just add the `id` of all elements (containing `itemprop` attributes) that should be added to the item to its `itemref` attribute, e.g.: `itemref="date author rating"`.

Comment: Wow, that `itemref` thing is awesome. Will definitely use that!

Comment: @unor: can you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083028/microdata-how-to-correctly-reference-item-from-meta-tag-in-header ?

Answer (score 10):

Remember also that it's possible to totally avoid HTML markup and use JSON-LD markup <s>entirely contained in the `<head>`</s> [**anywhere** in the HTML document (even dynamically injected!)](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org) like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Restaurant",
  "name": "Fondue for Fun and Fantasy",
  "description": "Fantastic and fun for all your cheesy occasions",
  "openingHours": "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su 11:30-23:00",
  "telephone": "+155501003333",
  "menu": "http://example.com/menu"
}
</script>
```

have a look at the examples in [schema.org](https://schema.org/), they usually contain JSON example markups like this https://schema.org/Restaurant.

Here is another good article about it http://www.seoskeptic.com/json-ld-google-knowledge-graph-schema-org-seo/

Answer (score 8):

What I can read from whatwg.org it's correct to use in body: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element

I use meta tags in the body of my blogg to specify the "datePublished" and "dateUpdated" properties. Googles [Rich Snippets Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) tells me it's correct and w3c validates the code.

Comment: Erik's experience mirrors my own. I had to move them to the body in order for the rich snippet testing tool to recognize them. Our search results in Google shows them properly extracting since we're seeing those attributes in the results.

Comment: `dateUpdated` no longer exists on this page [http://schema.org/docs/full.html](http://schema.org/docs/full.html)

Answer (score 5):

I do it this way:

```
<meta id="md_course" itemprop="course" name="course"   content="..."/>
<meta id="md_lang" itemprop="language" content="eng"/>
<title id="md_title" itemprop="title" >Motivation and Course Overview</title>
</head>
<body itemscope itemtype=".../Presentation" itemref="md_course md_lang md_title md_field">
```

Comment: according to Schema.org , when you use itemprop on meta tag u should omit name & ... and only use itemprop & content :)

Comment: It’s [not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669) to have an `itemprop` *and* a `name` attributes on `meta`. It’s either or. (And this comes directly from Microdata, not (only) from the Schema.org vocabulary.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
<meta itemprop="">
```

in the body of the page to do schema.org semantic markup that is machine readable (by robots, for SEO, for instance) even if you don't want to display the actual text (product name, for example) on the page.

see: http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing

> Sometimes, a web page has information that would be valuable to mark
>   up, but the information can't be marked up because of the way it
>   appears on the page. The information may be conveyed in an image (for
>   example, an image used to represent a rating of 4 out of 5) or a Flash
>   object (for example, the duration of a video clip), or it may be
>   implied but not stated explicitly on the page (for example, the
>   currency of a price).

Comment: lets not forget to use content on meta tag too !
<meta itemprop="" content="">

Answer (score 3):

When first working with schema.org's microdata, I added the meta tags in the head tag of my web page but when I ran that page against [Google's Rich Snippets Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), the data was not extracted. I then moved the meta tags into the body of the page and the data was shown as being extracted.