# Google's testing tool thinks product markup is incomplete. Why?

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

When I try a Product page at Google's Rich Snippets testing tool http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.camasicostume.ro%2Findex.php%3Froute%3Dproduct%2Fproduct%26product_id%3D478 I find that it is returning the error:

> Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.

Can't seem to figure out why. For product markup, only product name, price an currency are required per Google's policy: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750

Answer (score 4):

Problem is in this part of code

```
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <meta itemprop="price" content="99,00 Lei" />
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="Lei" />
  <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
</span>
```

At the [doc](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en) you mentioned

- Requirement for price

  > A floating point number. You may use either a decimal point ('.') or a comma (',') as a separator.

  So let's correct line with price:

  > meta itemprop="price" content="99,00"
- Requirement for currency

  > The currency used to describe the product price, in three-letter [ISO format](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/currency_codes.htm).

  And [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) hints us to use *RON* identifier for Romanian currency. After correction

  > meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RON"

Let's try this

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.camasicostume.ro/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=478" >
  <meta itemprop="name" content="wepa wepa " >
  <meta itemprop="model" content="X00851_PR013T2189" >
  <meta itemprop="manufacturer" content="Diesel" >

  <meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.camasicostume.ro/image/cache/imported/X00851_PR013T2189/stock_prod31697_image_1756005734-450x550.jpg" >

  <meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.camasicostume.ro/image/cache/imported/X00851_PR013T2189/stock_prod31697_image_1782593751-74x74.jpg" >

  <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="99,00" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RON" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
  </span>

  <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="1">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5">
  </span>
</span>
```

Perfect.

[image]

Comment: Though this isn't technically valid HTML, is it? Since <meta> data must be within <head>

Comment: @Spooky: It’s valid. [`link`/`meta` are allowed in the `body` when used for Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669).

Comment: @unor: thx, yes, didn't know that. This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/374996 lists the conditions under which a <meta> tag is valid or invalid within <body>

Comment: could anyone confirm that google allows the price being put in a meta-data-tag. In all samples I've seen it's not used like that.

Comment: Please be aware the statement  "You may use either a decimal point ('.')"  is no longer valid as of Sep 2018 and is not mentioned on the page from the link above https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en  anymore. Currently the recommendation is "Use '.' (Unicode 'FULL STOP' (U+002E)) rather than ',' to indicate a decimal point."   per https://schema.org/price .