# Image Microdata: Attribute a photo to a photographer

Tags: html, microdata

On my personal website, I have a photo of myself which was taken by a designer I once worked with. I would like to attribute her as the author of the photo using metadata, but if possible I would like to avoid adding visible elements to support this microdata. (I could use extra spans, etc, to hold text content; I could use a `figure` for this, perhaps, but I don't think that's the best way to do this.)

I've looked at schema.org, but it doesn't look as though there's an obvious way to add an author attribution without adding subelements to a parent element. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a meta tag which schema shows as well. 
Like :

```
<meta itemprop=author content="sue"/>
```

Nothing will render on the page that way. 
I think that's what you are asking at least. Keep in mind I oversimplified the answer since schema.org shows how to use properties.

Comment: You might like to show how you would attach the meta element to the item, given that the question discusses using a figure element as a container.

Comment: Agreed with Alohci. This looks like a great answer, but from what I understand you can only put meta tags in the head of the document. I don't believe that it supports the `for` attribute like form tags do - is there an equivalent?

Comment: I am a bit new so thanks. Basically the meta can go in the div that contains the image. So once the div closes that closes the micro data as well

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung: `meta`/`link` are [allowed in the `body` if used for Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669).