# W3C validation of Microdata itemref technique when combined with <meta>

Tags: html, w3c-validation, microdata

Consider this HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <a itemprop="url" href="//www.seashellswebsite.co.uk/">
            <img itemprop="logo" src="logo.gif" alt="Seaside Shells" title="Seaside Shells">
        </a>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Seaside Shells">
        <meta itemprop="legalName" content="Seaside Shells Ltd">
        <meta itemscope itemprop="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemref="schemaOrganizationAddress">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="We sell sea shells on the sea shore. The sea shells we sell are unfortunately rather overpriced.">
    </div>
</header>

<h1>Super Interesting Page</h1>
<p>Foo bar.</p>

<footer>
    <span id="schemaOrganizationAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">1 Seafront Road</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Fishing Town</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">Coastal County</span>,
        <span itemprop="postalCode">12345</span>
    </span>
</footer>
```

The W3C Validator complains thus:

> Element `meta` is missing required attribute `content`.

… and refers to this line:

```
<meta itemscope itemprop="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemref="schemaOrganizationAddress">
```

But what should the `content` attribute be here, given that the `itemref` attribute indicates that the content resides in another element outside the current scope? Surely the `content` attribute is surplus to requirement in this instance?

Comment: Note: Microdata defines [when it is allowed to have `meta` in `body`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669): the `content` attribute *must* be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by getting rid of that meta and putting `itemprop="address"` in the footer.

Then you can reference the container in the footer from the line with `itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"`.

The microdata in your code is valid though. It passes [Google's richsnippet validator](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

```
<header>
    <div id="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="schemaOrganizationAddress">
        <a itemprop="url" href="//www.example.com/">
            <img itemprop="logo" src="logo.gif" alt="Seaside Shells" title="Seaside Shells">
        </a>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Seaside Shells">
        <meta itemprop="legalName" content="Seaside Shells Ltd">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="We sell sea shells on the sea shore. The sea shells we sell are unfortunately rather overpriced.">
    </div>
</header>

<h1>Super Interesting Page</h1>
<p>Foo bar.</p>

<footer>
    <span id="schemaOrganizationAddress" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">1 Seafront Road</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Fishing Town</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">Coastal County</span>,
        <span itemprop="postalCode">12345</span>
    </span>
</footer>
```