# Multiple Time Elements with Microdata

Tags: html, date, time, microdata

I have a definition list representing my business' opening hours:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Monday - Friday</dt>
  <dd>8:30am to 5:30pm</dd>
  <dt>Saturday - Sunday</dt>
  <dd>9:00am to 5:00pm</dd>
  <dt>Holidays</dt>
  <dd>Closed</dd>
</dl>
```

This seems like a good, structured way to arrange this content. But perhaps I am wrong?

I am wondering how I would use the `time` element to represent the opening hours?

Ultimately, I was looking at doing something like this:

```
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 8:30-17:30">Monday - Friday, 8:30am to 5:30pm</time>
```

But with the days of the week in the `dt` tag and the hours in the `dd`'s, I'm not sure what the proper approach to the markup would be? Two different `time` tags seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With Microdata, you are not "annotating" your HTML markup. The markup serves only as a carrier. After a Microdata consumer parsed the page, there is no relation between the HTML and the Microdata items anymore.

So you have actually two questions:

- Which HTML5 markup should I use?
- How can I use this markup to add what I want to say with Microdata?

#### HTML5

The HTML5 question is easy: You can use the `time` element for everything that is a date, time, time-zone offset, or duration. So your `dl` could look like:

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Monday - Friday</dt>
    <dd><time datetime="08:30">8:30am</time> to <time datetime="17:30">5:30pm</time></dd> <!-- could also use a duration string instead, or an additional time element; but probably doesn’t make much sense in this context -->
  <dt>Saturday - Sunday</dt>
    <dd><time datetime="09:00">9:00am</time> to <time datetime="17:00">5:00pm</time></dd>
  <dt>Holidays</dt>
    <dd>Closed</dd>
</dl>
```

#### Schema.org and Microdata

Now looking at the definition of schema.org’s [`openingHours` property](http://schema.org/openingHours), we see that there is no mandatory content format: "Opening hours **can** be specified as […]" (emphasis mine).

However, the syntax they document/recommend as possible format is **invalid HTML5**: the [`time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) can’t have a datetime value like "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 8:30-17:30" or "Mo-Su" (I created an [issue](https://github.com/rvguha/schemaorg/issues/143)).

So if you want to use this documented format, you should not use the `time` element. Instead, you could

- use the [`data` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element) and its `value` attribute:

  ```
  <data itemprop="openingHours" value="Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 8:30-17:30">…</data>
  ```

  You could use it to wrap the content of the corresponding `dt` or `dd`, if you like.
- use a [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element):

  ```
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 8:30-17:30">
  ```

  You could place it as child of the corresponding `dt` or `dd`, if you like (yes, [in the `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669)).

You might want to use [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification) → [`OpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification) instead.