# After adding microdata not listed in google

Tags: html, google-search, microdata

In order to improve the search presence of my website, I added microdata to it (http://schema.org/Event, http://schema.org/Offer). But since I did this google can not find my website any more, even though google webmaster says that there are no problems and errors with it. The data is read correctly. before I added the microdata my website was on the third position when I searched for it. Now it is not listed with the same keywords.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
<meta itemprop="name" content="IGNITE THE NIGHT - Maturaball des BRG Kepler" />
<meta itemprop="url" content="www.keplerball.at" />
<meta itemprop="location" content="Kammersäle, Graz" />
<meta itemprop="image" content ="http://www.keplerball.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/vorschau_cropped_compressed.jpg" />
<b>WER?<br>
<table><tr><td>
MaturantInnen des BRG Kepler
</td></tr></table>
<br>
WANN?<table><tr>
    <td>Datum:</td>
    <td>Freitag, 28. November</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einlass:</td>
    <td><meta itemprop="startDate" content="2014-11-28T19:00">19 Uhr</time></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Polonaise:</td>
    <td>20:30 Uhr</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
PREISE<table>
    <tr>
            <td>VVK</td>
            <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <meta itemprop="price" content="16" />
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
            <meta itemprop="category" content="VVK" />
            <td>16€</td>
            </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AK</td>
        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="20" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
        <meta itemprop="category" content="AK" />
        <td>20€</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
WO? <br>
<table><tr><td>
Kammersäle
</td></tr></table>
<br>
DANACH?<br>
<table><tr><td>
Flann O'Brien
</td></tr></table>
</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not? How to it the right way?

Comment: @Hacketo Meta tags are one of the suggested ways of adding non-visible microdata. See the **Non-visible content** section in https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/176035?hl=en

Comment: Of course yes, but in this case, this should not be meta tags. the price is displayed, the date, the description ...

Comment: Usefull stuff for microdata : http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a SEO issue. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can know, you should add the `itemprop` values directly to the element:

Don't:

```
<td><meta itemprop="startDate" content="2014-11-28T19:00">...
```

Do:

```
<td itemprop="startDate" content="2014-11-28T19:00">...
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think search engines treat `<meta>` tags inside the `<body>` as malformed code.

Comment: @StefanSchuchlenz: It’s [valid if used for Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669) (or [for RDFa](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633)).