# Is it possible to use a page's meta description as microdata?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, microdata

i'm wondering if something like the following is fine..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Microdata Example</title>
    <meta id="site-description" name="description" content="description text here">
</head>
<body itemscope itemref="site-description" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Foo</h1>
    <img itemprop="image" src="bar.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won’t work.

The `itemref` attribute is used to reference Microdata properties, but your referenced `meta` element doesn’t have an `itemprop` attribute.

And you can’t add an `itemprop` attribute to the `meta` element [if it has a `name` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669).

If you don’t want to have this description visible on the page, you could

- add the `meta` element in the `head`, using `itemref`:

  ```
  <head>
      <meta name="description" content="description text here">
      <meta id="site-description" itemprop="description" content="description text here">
  </head>
  <body itemscope itemref="site-description" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  </body>
  ```
- add the `meta` element in the `body`, not using `itemref`:

  ```
  <head>
      <meta name="description" content="description text here">
  </head>
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
      <meta itemprop="description" content="description text here">
  </body>
  ```

(Assuming that you want to use Schema.org’s [`description` property](http://schema.org/description).)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i was hoping to find a solution that doesn't involve adding the description twice. guess it's not possible. no worries