# what is the current opinion on using <meta> tags to hide individual instances of a recurring itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"

Tags: schema.org, microdata

This event is a local farm market where the client will be making weekly appearances at a venue which shifts bi-annually.  Because the recurrence of the event is irregular (some weeks the start time may be different and the number of days between events varies between 7 and 5), there is plenty of justification to list them individually.  However, a human reader will not like the aesthetics of 20+ listings all having the same description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have to duplicate the description, you can use the [`itemref` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#attr-itemref):

```html
<p itemprop="description" id="farm-market">…<!-- description for all events --></p>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="farm-market">
  <time itemprop="startDate">2015-01-20</time>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="farm-market">
  <time itemprop="startDate">2015-02-04</time>
</div>
```

If you don’t want to show *any* content from the single events (i.e., not even the date), then yes, you should use `meta` elements in Microdata:

```html
<p itemprop="description" id="farm-market">…<!-- description for all events --></p>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="farm-market">
  <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2015-01-20">
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemref="farm-market">
  <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2015-02-04">
</div>
```

There’s nothing wrong about using `meta`.
It’s what gets used in [some examples](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#the-basic-syntax) from the Microdata (W3C Working Group Note) specification, and for this purpose Microdata defines that it’s [valid to use `meta` elements in the `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669).

Comment: I agree that itemref is going to be the right way to propagate those values.  My main question is how to include all events, but only show the human reader whatever content ive got in the description  `<p itemprop="description" id="farm-market">…<!-- description for all events --></p>`...  the main problem being that Google seems not to like microdata-bearing content that isnt visible

Comment: @user162241: Ah, then `meta` it is (updated my answer). Discussing what Google likes/not likes is off-topic here on Stack Overflow, unfortunately. However, you don’t really have a choice, do you? You don’t want to show the content, so it has to be hidden. And `meta` is the right way for hiding it. And on a side note: for some Rich Snippets, Google recommends the use of JSON-LD instead of Microdata, and JSON-LD is hidden all the time (in a `script`), so it’s not a "rule" that hidden metadata is frowned upon by Google. However, for obvious reasons visible content is usually the better choice.