# Meta tag breaking HTML validation when using it with schema.org breadcrumblist

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, schema.org, microdata

I am using the breadcrumb list from schema.org. They state that we need to use a meta tag to specify the order of the items.

- It breaks my HTML validation, is there any other way of specifying order?
- The meta tag is adding a space before the word Brands

Here is my markup:

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="/">
      <span itemprop="name">My Website</span>
    </a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="active">
    <span itemprop="item">
      <span itemprop="name">Brands</span>
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

The output would look like this:

```
My Website / Brands
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet is valid HTML5 (the [`meta` element may appear in the `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669) if used for Microdata, which is the case in your example).

Using the `meta` element is the correct choice if you don’t want to display the value. You may place it anywhere inside the `ListItem` (e.g., on the same line next to the link or name, to omit creating whitespace).

Note that you don’t *have* to use the `position` property. Schema.org never requires any properties.

Comment: (You may want to provide the URL of the last/current item in a `link` element. If not, I guess there is no reason to provide the `item` property.)

Comment: My last item is the current page. Should I still include it as a link?

Comment: @BrendanVogt: I guess it’s your choice: either use `item` for the last entry (and specify the URL), or omit `item` (and don’t specify the URL). (I don’t know what consumers of the data might prefer.)