# How to add microdata to price field?

Tags: drupal-7, microdata

We have a content type called product which has a custom "input" button that allows you to "add to cart". So I have this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now $'.$content['field_price'][0]['#markup'].'" alt="Buy Now $'.$content['field_price'][0]['#markup'].'" />
```

The problem is that the price field is inside an input field, and therefore not displayed, so I would have to show the price some other way to include it within the product page.

The sample that I have shows the price on the page, but I don't want to show the price, because it's already shown in my input field. So this won't work:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>
  <img src="kenmore-microwave-17in.jpg" alt='Kenmore 17" Microwave' />
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price">$55.00</span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />In stock
  </div>
</div>
```

The only way I see this working is I do something sneaky like this:

```
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price" style="displaY: none;">$55.00</span>
  </div>
```

Would that be allowed or is that not going to solve my problem?

**UPDATE**

This works:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="price" style="displaY: none;">$55.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <meta itemprop="price" itemprop="55.00" />
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" itemprop="USD" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `meta` element.

In HTML5+Microdata ([as well as in HTML+RDFa](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633)) the [`meta` element may be used in the `body` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669), exactly for this purpose. It’s the same idea as using the `link` element for the `availability` property (like in your example).

In Microdata, it could look like this:

```html
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <meta itemprop="price" content="55.00" />
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried adding it here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ ... I'll update my question with more info.

Comment: @coderama: Sorry, I had a typo in my example: the second attribute should be `content`, not a duplicated `itemprop`. I corrected it.