# How to correctly reference Microdata item from meta tag in header?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
<head>
  <meta itemprop="creator" itemscope itemref="mdFoo">
</head>
<body>

 <div id="mdFoo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Foo comp">
        <meta itemprop="telephone" content="0">
        <meta itemprop="legalName" content="Foo comp Ltd">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.foo.com">
        <meta itemprop="email" content="info@foo.com">
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="mystreet">
            <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="1233">
            <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="London">
            <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="UK">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

when validating with Google ( https://google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/ ): "WebSite is not a valid type."

Using https://validator.nu/ gives me "Element meta is missing required attribute content".

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279277/do-you-put-schema-microdata-meta-tags-in-the-html-body

Comment: Start by terminating your `meta` tags with `/>`.

Comment: Why? <meta> is also correct. This is not needed, same for <img>. It is html5 not xhtml...
see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: Note that you linked to Google’s testing tool for emails. The testing tool you probably want is https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the `itemref` on the `itemscope` to which you want to add properties (i.e., the `html` element in your case). And the element with the corresponding `id` would have to get the `itemprop`.

However, in your case you don’t need the `meta` element, and you don’t need to use `itemref`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
<head>
  <title>…</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div itemprop="creator" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But let’s say you use another `itemscope` (e.g., for a `WebPage` item) on the `body`, in which case you’d need to use `itemref`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite" itemref="mdFoo">
<head>
  <title>…</title>
</head>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

  <div itemprop="creator" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" id="mdFoo">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now the `creator` property will be applied to both items (`WebSite` thanks to `itemref`, and `WebPage` because it’s a child).