# Why is it necessary to provide a 'value' in this 'LocationFeatureSpecification' item?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm trying to add semantic markup to my website through [schemas](http://schema.org). I want to list the services of a Hotel so I'm taking a look at the [`LocationFeatureSpecification`](http://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification). I have the following example, which is a list of hotel features:

```html
<ul>
<li itemprop="amenityFeature" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification">
 <span itemprop="name">Sauna</span>
 <meta itemprop="value" content="True">
</li>
<li itemprop="amenityFeature" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification">
 <span itemprop="name">Gym</span>
 <meta itemprop="value" content="True">
</li>
</ul>
```

So my question is, why is a `value` here necessary? Can it be omitted to imply a default "true" value?

Also, I'd like to give information on whether the service is free or paid (without saying any amount). How can I do that with this property when [its description clearly states](http://schema.org/amenityFeature):

> This generic property does not make a statement about whether the feature is included in an offer for the main accommodation or available at extra costs.

Comment: There may be another issue here. Google SDTT does not appear to properly handle `amenityFeature` as a property of `@Place`. @unor is the authority here and we may want to wait until he weighs in on this. As an aside, the `<meta>` definition is optional. If you want to markup pricing information, you'll need to use `@Offer`. Offer has flexible terms for expressing price.

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I'm wondering what if schema.org has a certain specification and Google SDTT has another? which one should you use? but I guess this should be posted as another question...

Comment: The terms `amenityFeature`/`LocationFeatureSpecification`/etc. are only two days old, and Google’s SDTT typically needs some time until they recognize new terms. -- If Google decides to offer a related search feature (e.g., displaying a hotel rich snippet), they would ideally conform to the definition in Schema.org. Otherwise, what’s the point of using Schema.org in the first place? And they are a Schema.org sponsor after all. But Google would of course require certain properties/types -- Schema.org says "you can use this", Google says "you have to use this and this, *if* you want our feature"

Answer (score 1):

You may omit the [`value` property](http://schema.org/value), just like you may omit every other property, as Schema.org never requires any.

It’s not explicitly defined how a [`LocationFeatureSpecification`](http://schema.org/LocationFeatureSpecification) without a `value` should be interpreted (i.e., there is no "default" value defined), but I think it’s conceivable that consumers will interpret it as a feature the location *has*.
But it’s of course also possible that some consumers will require the `value` property, so if you want to be on the safe side, you might want to provide `value` even in case its value is *true*. If you have many amenity features, you could use Microdata’s `itemref` attribute: only provide one `meta` element and reference it from all `LocationFeatureSpecification` items ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669)).

There doesn’t seem to be a way to explicitly state which amenity feature is gratis/included or non-gratis/optional. You can create corresponding `Offer` items for the features, like the [Schema.org Hotels documentation](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html) suggests:

> For modeling the fees of optional room features, you can link the [offer](http://schema.org/Offer) for the room to an offer for the feature or service via the [addOn](http://schema.org/addOn) property.