# How can Date Published or Date Modified meta tag in blogger.com header?

Tags: blogger, meta-tags

In Blogger.com many conditional value used for extracting data from blog in a specific meta attributes. Such as

```
<meta name="description" expr:content="metaDescription"/>
```

here metaDescription retrieve the page description from the blog.

What is the conditional value for replacing date published in meta content attributes? Like

```
<meta name="date_published" content"??????"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve published date of posts and use that as meta tag you have to rely on [Schema](http://schema.org/) structured data markup.

To do that copy and paste this following codes just below `post hentry uncustomized-post-template` div elements.

`<meta expr:content='data:post.dateHeader' itemprop='datePublished'/>`

You can also add this following codes to tell the search engines when did you last update your blog post.

```
<meta expr:content='data:post.lastUpdatedISO8601' itemprop='dateModified'/>
```

To check if this retrieving the post publish date and post update date properly, simply go to [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool) and fetch the url of your blog post.

Here @Unor described in details [why you should not put this schema meta tags inside `<head>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/4754246).

Comment: this_> '<meta expr:content='data:post.lastUpdatedISO8601' itemprop='dateModified'/>' more effective since it includes 'ISO8601'.

Answer (score 0):

I think date data only available on post widget like blog widget and popular post widget. It's not possible in head tag.

Comment: right.. I tried too much. It's bad for Blogger to optimize SEO